# Data in list is not binding to HTML but showing the list on console in Ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework

My data suddenly stopped binding to UI while it is displayed on console correctly

here is my code

this is my html file

```
<ion-content>   
 <ion-card *ngFor="let product of selectedproducts; let i = index">
  <ion-item class="bigclass" *ngIf="length>0"><p>{{product.image}}</p>
  <ion-thumbnail item-start>       
    <img-loader [src]="product.image" useImg></img-loader>
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <h4 top text-wrap>{{product.name}}</h4>
  <p>Rs.{{product.price*product.quantity}}</p>
  <button  class="dec"  (click)="decrement(product)" 
   [disabled]="product.disabled"><ion-icon  icon-only  
   name="remove-circle">
 </ion-icon></button>
    Quantity:{{product.qtyy}}
    <button  class="inc"  (click)="increment(product)" 
    [disabled]="product.disabled" ><ion-icon   icon-only 
    name="add-circle" ></ion-icon></button>

</ion-item>
```

The loop is working fine and it is showing other static elements correctly but not the ones that are binded.
This is my .ts file

```
 constructor(private storage: Storage,public navCtrl: NavController) {
this.storage.get('listforcartproducts').then((val) => {
 this.selectedproducts =val;
  console.log(this.selectedproducts);    
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your data and the desired behavior? What "binded" elements do you mean?

Comment: {name: "ZUCCHINI/ TURAI (YELLOW)", id: 3319, price: 296, qtyy: 8, image: "https://wowvegetables.com/wp-content/uploads/1.jpg"}
This is a sample of data that I am trying to bind.And it was working fine till yesterday and suddenly it gets stucked

Like the "name" object has the value and I want it to get bind with the <h4> tag,the one present in my html file

Comment: I have a working StackBlitz right here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-h57krk. Are you sure there isn't something wrong with your data or something undefined? Maybe `length` is not defined.

Comment: No everything is clear and defined.